# Default values and not null constraints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.1**

**spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**

**postgres 12.5**

A short excerpt from an entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter    

@Entity
public class Branch extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;    

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default ''", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default ''")
    private String segmentFour;
}
```

The entity generates a table like this:

This is it:

```
ads=# \d clients__branch

                                          Table "public.clients__branch"
            Column         |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
    -----------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
     id                    | integer                |           | not null | generated by default as identity
     name                  | character varying(255) |           | not null | ''::character varying
     segment_four          | character varying(255) |           |          | ''::character varying
```

We can see that:

1. "name" is not null and has a default value ''.
2. "segment_one" has a default value, but there is no not null constraint.

Let's try to use this.

Let's fill the data and save it:

```
Branch branch0 = new Branch();
branch0.setName("Train");
branch0.setSegmentFour("");


Branch branch1 = new Branch();
branch1.setName("Car");
branch1.setSegmentFour(null);

Branch branch2 = new Branch();
branch2.setName("Ship");
```

Result:

```
ads=# select id, name, case when segment_four is null then 'null' when segment_four = '' then 'space' end as segment from clients__branch;
 id |  name   | segment 
----+---------+---------
  1 | Vosst   | space
  2 | Ryba    | null
  3 | Admiral | null
```

**Problems**

1. I'd like to prevent anybody to from setting Null as in case with
   branch1.
2. If I organize it like this:

   @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default ''", nullable =
   false) private String segmentFour;

   then I get:

   ```
   ERROR: null value in column "segment_four" violates not-null constraint
   ```
3. I'd like to have a default value (the code for branch2 should
   generate '' in the segment_four).

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to handle this using [@Column](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation, but you can own logic in the setter method to make it to empty if value is null

```
public void setSegmentFour(String segmentFour) {
 this.segmentFour = segmentFour == null ? "" : segmentFour;
 }
```

Comment: It is too complicated. It will bring tons of code here. Now I use lombok's getter, setter.

Comment: I guess it is only one extra line, even lombok creats the same code without that condition @Kifsif

Comment: it is just an example. I'll have to refactor tons of code in a real project. For every field.

Comment: maybe lombok setter can have a default value?

Comment: A simpler approach is to initialize the field at its declaration (`private String segmentFour = "";`). Then you don't have to give the accessor methods side-effects. Of course this won't cover the scenario when someone explicitly sets a field to `null`, which is covered by the above solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `@ColumnDefault` with `@DynamicInsert` in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class Branch extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;    

    @Column
    @ColumnDefault("''")
    private String name;

    @Column
    @ColumnDefault("''")
    private String segmentFour;
    
    // ...
}
```

and then just omit to set value for the field if you want to use the default value.
The entity above is annotated with the `@DynamicInsert` annotation so that the `INSERT` statement does not include any entity attribute that does not contain a value.

See additional explanation in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value).